# How do I grep audio/video frame time indexes from an XML file?

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

I have a xml file like this:

```
<field name="frame.time_delta_displayed" showname="Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.000000000 seconds" size="0" pos="0" show="0.000000000"/>
<field name="frame.time_delta_displayed" showname="Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.000201000 seconds" size="0" pos="0" show="0.000201000"/>
<field name="frame.time_delta_displayed" showname="Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.000595000 seconds" size="0" pos="0" show="0.000595000"/>
```

I want to grep all the values in the show="xxx" part, the output would be:

```
0.000000000
0.000201000
0.000595000
...
```

is it possible to do that by using grep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -Po '(?<=show=")[^"]*' filename.xml
```

`(?<=show=")[^"]*` matches `xxxx` in `show="xxxx"` and grep option `-o` prints only those text matched.